# DecimalPadのキーボードの小数点をピリオド固定にする方法はありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, localization

ローカライズ対応中のアプリで、キーボードのDecimalPadを指定している箇所があります。
iOSの設定アプリの書式の設定でイタリアを選択すると、DecimalPadのピリオドがカンマになりますが、これだと少々具合が悪い為(DBに値を入れて集計したりする為)、設定を無視して常にピリオドを表示するキーボードを表示させたいのですが、これは可能でしょうか？
できればカスタムキーボードの実装は避けて、簡単な方法を探しております。

Answer (score 1):

直接の回答ではありませんが、ローカライズ対応と言うことであれば、DecimalPadもローカライズ対応したものを表示すべきではないでしょうか。

「DBに値を入れて集計」と言うことであれば、`NSNumberFormatter`を使えば、現在のユーザ設定に応じたフォーマットで数値データを解釈してくれますので、DecimalPadにコンマが表示される設定であれば、コンマを小数点として解釈してくれます。

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
if let value = numberFormatter.numberFromString(textField.text ?? "")?.doubleValue {
    print(value)
}
```

数値型の値を画面に表示する場合にも`NSNumberFormatter()`を使用することになります。

```
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10
textField.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(123.456)
//->イタリア語の状態では、123,456 と表示される
```

日本人スタッフばかりで「ローカライズ対応」を行うと、つい表示される文言の翻訳にばかり気を取られがちですが、「小数点」「日付の書式」(日本流のyyyy/MM/dd形式は欧米ではほとんど使われません)なども、しっかりローカライズした方が良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 仰る通りかと思います。だんだん面倒に感じてきて楽な方法に逃げようと考えていましたが、目が覚めました(笑) ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: iPad版ですとピリオドもカンマも入力できてしまうのですが、カンマ入力のロケールでもピリオドで入力された値をOKとするか悩ましいです。ロケールの設定に則した入力でないとNG！とバッサリ切って良いものでしょうか？

Comment: @花の命は短い さん、私もiPad版までは念頭にありませんでした。ただ、コンマを小数点に使う地域の多くでは、ピリオドを千倍ごとの3桁区切りに使うので、どちらでもと言う対応はかえって混乱を招きそうな気がします。他のアプリの使い勝手にまで精通した現地スタッフがいれば良いんですが、なかなか悩ましいですね。

Comment: 再度のご回答ありがとうございます！私も3桁区切りまでは頭が回っていませんでした^^; 自身が一番混乱していますのでまずはバッサリ切る方向で進めたいと思います。